Position camera to 'head' joint's position in skeletal animation
Finished this great tutorial on skeletal animation:
https://learnopengl.com/Guest-Articles/2020/Skeletal-Animation
All works as expected, no issues!
Here is what matrixes I use to achieve skeletal animation:
ModelMatrix: model matrix of the player's model, which brings the vertex from model space to world space.
InverseBindMatrix (offset matrix in the tutorial): brings the vertex from model space to bone space.
FinalBoneMatrix: which is the transformation of the current animation pose, passed to vertex shader. Combined with the ModelMatrix, it gives the posed vertex position in world space.
As a next step, I wish to position the camera to the 'head' joint's position.
I thought it would be simply:
vec3 headPosition = ModelMatrix * FinalBoneMatrixes["head"][3]; //col 3 is the translation part in 4x4 column major matrix.

but that just position the camera into the stomach of the player model. Minimal offsetting comes through, but clearly the camera is not on, and doesn't follow the head joint's position.
I have all the info in place, and I thought that I understood the involved transformations, but seems not the case.
Could somebody describe the series of transformation required to get joint/bone positions in world space?

I looked at your tutorial code and I don't see the public accessors that your indicate in your question.  I'm assuming you mean using the Animation m_FinalBoneMatrices which is not a dictionary of matrices.  So I think your question is a a little incomplete and vague.  It does appear that if your Animation class is calculating the final matrices of the bones relative to the world transform that you should be able to do what you want with what you have said in your question.
I think the answer may lie in the incomplete part of where are you getting the the "head" matrix from?

i build a map of the bones, where the key is a string. So FinalBoneMatrixes["head"] gives me back the head matrix. Its calculation is exactly as it is in the tutorial.

Found the solution, i need to multiply with finalBoneMatrix with the inverse of the InverseBindMatrix, and ofc the model matrix to move it to world space.

Can you show the corresponding line(s) of code, to make the multiplication order completely unambiguous?

I think you want to multiply the two matrices together and pull the transform out.
You are pulling the translation vector out of the final bone matrix but omitting the scaling and rotation.
Try this:
vec3 headPosition = (ModelMatrix * FinalBoneMatrixes["head"])[3];


thanks, but rotation is essential, see my answer
